# Redis caching and queuing on same server?

Tags: flask, caching, redis

I am using Redis for caching and queuing of a flask application. However, I observe that my cache object also has worker job related entries which are breaking my cache data fetching code.

Is there any way I can use redis for serving both purpose together ?

Comment: You can use multiple databases one for caching and another for queueing.

Comment: Yes, Actually I have only one terminal where I am deploying on which 'redis-server' is running, how do I start the 'rq worker' there . Do I need to make changes the way I am deploying redis ?